# Bound Service vs Unbound + singleton for communication

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I have a service, I need to communicate to with it (one service - many fragments/activities). There are two options for this:

1. Have a singleton that controls the service - starts it and then binds to it (using the app context)
2. Have a singleton that controls the service - starts it, the service when ready registers back as a delegate to the singleton (in a `WeakReference`)

Solution no 2 seems simpler to me, but whenever I read about communication with services there is the concept of the bound service.

Is there any benefit of having a bound service instead of the service registering itself as a delegate (and unregistering with `onDestroy`)?

**Edit 1**: The service is to keep the communication alive, it's expensive to set up a new communication channel. Even if no one requested any data it should keep the channel alive (heartbeat).

The service is foreground, it should run even if the activity that requested the data gets killed by the system. The next time it is created the data will be there.
The data requested by one screen might be useful for some other (therefore has to be stored in a singleton).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bound and unbound services are both usable patterns and you should pick whatever pattern is better for you use case.

You should pick bound service if you want your service to have the same lifecycle as the components that bind to it. If you need an independent service use an unbound version.

The only benefit of one approach versus another is the simplicity of implementation.

In you case, I think you need the service only while there are running activities and fragments, then the easiest way, in my opinion, would be to make a bound service and make every activity bind to it. With that, you'll get a simple communication interface between you activities (and fragments, since they have access to containing activity) and your service.
The benefits of this approach are:

- the service will stop itself if all activities unbind and start itself when first activity binds to it.
- you won't need to track all running activities in the singleton and manually unbind
- you won't need to maintain a singleton manager, less code -> less bugs
- sometimes onDestroy can be skipped by the system and you can leak the service with the 2 approach.

---

Since you need your service to be running the correct option will be to use a started service and make each activity bind to it when needed. It's a common pattern.

Started service will run until you explicitly stop it or it stops itself, you can have a singleton manager that will be responsible for that.

But at the same time you can communicate with the service from your activity using binding.

So basically comparing with the first suggested approach, you'll need some instance that will start and stop the service, but the communication between activities and service will be the same - using binding.

Comment: Didn't know `onDestory()` might be skipped. I added some edits to my original question.

Comment: I get it know, if you bind directly from an activity or a fragment, the service wouldn't know where to register itself. But if you want to have some abstraction layer and you would bind from a singleton, that this really doesn't matter as the binder returns a reference to a service anyway.

Comment: You don't really need to bind in the singleton, you can just call `context.startForegroundService()`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a bound service in Android is a much better option when communicating with Views like Activities/Fragments. This is because of the following reasons,

1. It runs synchronously.
2. You can have more control on the service data when to show on UI thread of the view. You can choose when to call it in async/sync way.
3. LocalBroadcastManager only runs Asynchronously.